# Gensim: error while loading doc2vec model?

Tags: python-3.x, doc2vec

I stored my Doc2Vec model after training into disk and then when i tried to load the model back from disk it showed me some error

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile

def save_d2v_to_disk(model,fname):
    fn = get_tmpfile(fname)
    model.save(fn)

def load_d2v_from_disk(fname):
    fn = get_tmpfile(fname)
    model = Doc2Vec.load(fname)
    return model
```

Error it gave me

```
    >>> model = load_d2v_from_disk("model_d2v_version_002")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 3, in load_d2v_from_disk
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 1113, in load
        return super(Doc2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 1244, in load
        model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 603, in load
        return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 426, in load
        obj = unpickle(fname)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1386, in unpickle
        return _pickle.loads(f.read())
    cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '-'.
    >>>
```

I searched in google regarding this error but didn't find anything, please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to be using the `gensim.test.utils.get_tmpfile` function in this way. It simply creates a filename inside the system's 'temporary' directory - which in some cases might change over time, and on some systems will be automatically cleared of older files occasionally. If you need to save a model for future reuse, it'd be better to save it in an explicit location under your control.

That said, the location should work OK if just needed briefly, as in a full-cycle test that creates, saves, loads, and deletes files in short order. However, in that case, you should be saving aside the exact file path that was created by the save routine, then re-using that exact name – rather than calling `get_tmpfile()` twice.

If a `Doc2Vec` `.save()` has been done correctly, immediately beforehand, I wouldn't expect to see this sort of error.

Are you sure the `"model_d2v_version_002"` file was saved using `.save()`, without errors? (Do you have logging output from the time-of-saving, confirming success?)

After saving, can you verify its existence (along with possible supporting files) at the chosen location, by listing all files in that directory?